# Getting properties from a variable function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

I have this code:

```
var rect2 = new drawRect({
        h: 100,
        w: 100,
        x: 280,
        y: 20,
        colour: '8CB5CF',
        name: 'Office 2'
}
```

Is it possible for read the properties that I am passing to drawRect?
My first thought was:

```
alert(rect2.h)
```

But that results in `undefined`, didn't expect it to work really but I don't know how else to approach this.

I am fairly new to javascript. Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry here is drawRect:

```
    function drawRect(rectOptions){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle = rectOptions.colour;
        ctx.fillRect(rectOptions.x,rectOptions.y,rectOptions.h,rectOptions.w);
        ctx.font = '12px sans-serif';
        ctx.fillText(rectOptions.name, rectOptions.w + rectOptions.x, rectOptions.h     + rectOptions.y);
    }
```

here is the full code: [Full code](http://pastebin.com/LMAECVT7)

Comment: Could you provide the code for `drawRect`? That may provide a bit more insight on what's achievable.

Comment: where are you getting drawRect From? is that another function in your javascript file?

Comment: your code is broken , and we cant guess what drawRect is doing without looking at drawRect definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of the `drawRect` function you could add a line to add an `option` property to objects constructed by `drawRect`.

```
function drawRect(rectOptions) {
  this.options  = rectOptions;
  //...
}
```

Then you could do

```
var rect2 = new drawRect({ /* ... */ });
alert(rect2.options.h);
```

Alternatively, you could have `drawRect` return the options passed to it.

```
function drawRect(rectOptions) {
  //...
  return rectOptions;
}
```

Then you could do, as you originally tried,

```
alert(rect2.h);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I was aware of how the options property works. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jerrod Good to know ;) Once the 15 minute time limit is up, you can mark the answer that helped you the most by pressing the green checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rect2 = new drawRect({
        h: 100,
        w: 100,
        x: 280,
        y: 20,
        colour: '8CB5CF',
        name: 'Office 2'
})
 function drawRect(rectOptions){
        //your code
        return rectOptions;//you have to return the value 
    }

alert(rect2.h);//alerts 100
```

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jAb2z/)